# Required traces gatherer did not run

Tags: wordpress

I'm receiving this kind of error as in topic:

https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/http-aqustec-com/c6dd57pt7w?form_factor=mobile

What can be the reason for that?

I have tried to test it on my own server, but the original copy on my server gives the same error. The website is based on: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-themes-muffingroup-com-be-furniturestore/46yeq7nx72?form_factor=desktop